# how to display text in countdowntimer when the thread is sleeping in android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, thread-sleep

I am trying to create a countdown using the countdown timer. When the thread is sleeping I want the string value to display textview and this to display for 10 seconds before the countdown timer starts again.normally,countdown will go from 0 to 9 continuously. i want to set string value when the thread is sleeping. I am unsure how to get this working. this is my countdowntimer coding, Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
public class MyCountDownTimer2 extends CountDownTimer {
  public MyCountDownTimer2(long startTime2, long interval2) {
    super(startTime2, interval2);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
    countDownTimer2.start();                  
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    text2.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 10);                   
  }
}
```

if i press stop button i need to display this string value to countdowntimer textview for 10 seconds this is my string value code

```
public void stop(){              
  try {     
    String val2=text.getText().toString();
    int val3 = Integer.parseInt(val2);

    int num1,num2,num3,num4,temp;

    num1 = val3%10;
    temp = val3/10;

    String s4 = Integer.toString(num1);
    text1.setText(String.valueOf(s1));
  }
}
```

i tried this method my value is updated in my countdown textview but i cannot see that value with in fraction of seconds it has gone i need to display atleast 10 or 15 secs what can i do?

```
public class MyCountDownTimer1 extends CountDownTimer {
  public MyCountDownTimer1(long startTime1, long interval1) {
     super(startTime1, interval1);
 }

 @Override
public void onFinish() {
  countDownTimer1.start();
 }
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 text1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 10);
 String val2=text.getText().toString();
 int val3 = Integer.parseInt(val2);
 int num1,num2,num3,num4,temp;
 num1 = val3%10;
 temp = val3/10;

 num2=temp%10;
 temp=temp/10;

 num3=temp%10;
 num4=temp/10;

final String s1 = Integer.toString(num4);
 new Thread(){
  public void run(){
   try {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
     text1.setText(String.valueOf(s1));
   }
});
Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}.start();
}
}
```

Comment: @isim could you please solve my problem

Comment: Are you calling setText for TextView from gui thread or some other thread? It must be gui thread otherwise you won't see changes.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are trying to display the remaining seconds in the countdown when the timer is paused? And 10 seconds later, the timer will automatically resume its countdown?

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz can you tell me how to call setText for TextView from gui thread or some other thread

Comment: @isim almost same concept here i am counting 0 to 9 continuously if i click stop button i need to stop countdown for 10 seconds and display my string value for 10secs after that countdown will start normally this is the concept i need could you please help me

Comment: @rizwan Not sure how to do that. So when you click the stop button, your `MyCountDownTimer2` paused and display the remaining time for 10 seconds, then automatically resume the countdown? That sounds weird...

Comment: activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
//call set text here
}
})

Comment: @isim normally countdown is running. if i click stop MyCountDownTimer2 get paused and for ex: display some text like "wait" instead of string value for 10secs after that countdown will start narmally is it possible or not

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz where i have to put this activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ //call set text here } })  inside stop() or on finish function

Comment: in onTick() you need this style to update TextView

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz i am getting nullpointerexception from this line activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() what can i do? i am a fresher please tell me clear

Comment: post some more code and I will tell you.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz i tried as what you said but i can't see my updated value, i have to see atleast 10 or 15 secs

Comment: Try calling invalidate() on textview right after setText()

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz i tried like this as you said text1.invalidate(); but still i am not getting correct output, i need to display my value on textview for 10 seconds. could you please edit my code and post it?